# Distance of a compact set and a closed set

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove it. If possible let, $d(F,K)=0$. Then we must have at least one $x\in K$ such that $d(x,F)=0$ (It's my intuition,i have seen this result nowhere). Then for any small positive $r$ we must have $y\in F$ such that $d(x,y)<r$. It implies $x$ is a limit point of $F$. Since $F$ is closed $x\in F$ which is a contradiction as $F$ and $K$ are disjoint. So $d(F,K)>0$. But i haven't use the compactness of $K$, So i guess ...My argument is wrong! Where did i misstake?
I have another problem,i want a closed and totally bounded set complete but not compact.

Comment: "Then we must have at least one $x\in K$ such that $d(x,F)=0$", or more generally, such that $d(x,F)=d(K,F)$, definitely uses the compactness of $K$. Think about the two closed, non-compact sets in the plane given by the $x$-axis, and the graph of $y=1/x$. They have distance $0$, but there is no point on any of the two sets which is distance zero from the other set.

Comment: about your second problem, note that a closed subset in a complete metric space is complete. A complete and totally bounded set is compact. And such a set must maintain some positive distance with any other arbitrary closed set

Comment: Sorry...It's a very trivial question.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is closed, and $K$ is compact, inside some metric space, and $F\cap K\ne\emptyset$, then $d(F,K)>0$. For $x\in K$, $\phi(x)=d(F,x)$ defines a continuous function on $K$. (Note that $|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|\le d(x,y)$.)
By compactness, $\phi$ has a minimum $\delta$ on $K$. Then $\delta>0$
and also $d(F,K)=\delta$.

Your "intuition" is valid **because** of the compactness of $K$.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it.I tried from the fact that d is Uniformly continuous as K is compact but then I'm stuck...please help me

Comment: A continuous function from a nonempty compact space to $\Bbb R$ attains its bounds.